# Generating a Voronoi Diagram around 2D Polygons

Tags: python, graph, graphics, scipy, pygame

I'm trying to create a Voronoi diagram around 2D holes (preferably in PyGame or scipy, but not necessary) and save the edges. It should look something like this: [image]

I have been able to use [scipy's Voronoi](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) to generate a diagram around points, but I'm not sure how to proceed with 2D obstacles.

My code for working with points is:

```
self.vor = Voronoi(POINTS)

# iterate over voronoi graph and save edges
for vpair in self.vor.ridge_vertices:
    if vpair[0] >= 0 and vpair[1] >= 0:
        # vertices
        v0 = self.vor.vertices[vpair[0]]
        v1 = self.vor.vertices[vpair[1]]

        # edge endpoints
        start_point = (v0[0], v0[1])  # start point
        end_point = (v1[0], v1[1])
```

Basically, I want to input 2D obstacles (which could also be adjacent/touching so as to form a larger obstacle) and generate a set of lines which are equidistant from those obstacles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction you need is a medial axis. One way of constructing an approximate medial axis is to generate a constrained Delaunay triangulation of the space between the holes. Edges of the medial axis are then formed by connecting the circumcentres of adjacent triangles. There's quite a good matlab tutorial [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/creating-and-editing-delaunay-triangulations.html). Example 8 is the relevant bit.

Unfortunately, scipy doesn't have an implementation of constrained Delaunay triangulation. It just has unconstrained Delaunay triangulations and Vornoi diagrams, which are dual to each other. You will need something else. [Triangle](http://dzhelil.info/triangle/) is commonly used, and appears to have python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a mini python package to make it - [voronoi-diagram-for-polygons](https://github.com/longavailable/voronoi-diagram-for-polygons). You can find an example output from [here](https://github.com/longavailable/voronoi-diagram-for-polygons). It should be pointed out in advance that this package depends on v1.8.dev0 of [shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) which is still in development. In other words, it cannot be installed by `pip` automatically. You have to install it by the following:

`pip install git+https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely`.